# Can't acces dictionary value by itteration on expression generated dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a dictionary which I have generated with an expression, My goal is to compare class values and return the name of the object which meets a certain condition I just thought that it will be easy to accomplish by creating a dictionary, I did it like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

variants = 3
variants = dict({'v' + str(num): num for num in range(1, variants + 1, 1)})
```

**p.s.** I'm doing it this way because it's a part of a much more complex code.

In the given class the objects are:

```
v1 = A('v1', 201)
v2 = A('v2', 200)
v3 = A('v3', 2)
```

but now if I'm trying to access the values of the `variants` dict all it does is it's splitting the `key` instead of delivering it next to the `value`:

```
for key, value in variants:
print(key, value)
      #out
v 1
v 2
v 3
```

If i'm trying to print each entry:

```
for x in variants:
print(x)
    #out
v1
v2
v3
```

while If i'm trying to print out the whole dictionary, it works...

```
print(variants)
    #out
{'v1': 1, 'v2': 2, 'v3': 3}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you don't need `dict(...)` in `dict({'v' + str(num): num for num in range(1, variants + 1, 1)})`... `{'v' + str(num): num for num in range(1, variants + 1, 1)}` *already produces a dictionary*

Comment: You should do `for key, value in variants.items()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah I know, I just tried it in case it would solve the issue... I't didn't tho

Comment: Anyway, iterating over a dictionary *iterates over the keys*. `for key, value in variants` then, assigns each key to `key, value`, this *happens* to work because your keys are length 2 always, hence the output.

Comment: ```key, value``` iterates over the keys. The key is exactly 2 characters long. It are splitted among these 2

Comment: You can do `for key, value in varients.items()` or just `for value in varients.values()`

Comment: Thanks guys, post it as answers I'll accept, I't was my mistake i guess

Comment: As suggested in the above comments, you should use `variants.items()` for both keys and values and `variants.keys()` for only keys.

Comment: @Priya no, you should just use `for key in variants` for only the keys

Comment: @juanpa.rrivillaga yes agreed...thank you for correcting me  :-)